# Exception error while using find() in an unordered map

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using the book SFML Game Development by Example (Raimondas Pupius) to create a simple game engine (chapter 7). I get the code to compile, but the game crashes when I try to load the map (a text file) and I can't find what's wrong. While loading tiles I'm of course also loading the required graphics from the tile sheet, using this:

```
bool RequireResource(const std::string& l_id) {
    auto res = Find(l_id); // <-- Crash here.
    if (res) {
        ++res->second;
        return true;
    }
    auto path = m_paths.find(l_id);
    if (path == m_paths.end()) { return false; }
    T* resource = Load(path->second);
    if (!resource) { return false; }
    m_resources.emplace(l_id, std::make_pair(resource, 1));
    return true;
}
```

Find() seems to be the culprit, it looks like this:

```
std::pair<T*, unsigned int>* Find(const std::string& l_id) {
    auto itr = m_resources.find(l_id);              // <-- Crash here.
    return (itr != m_resources.end() ? &itr->second : nullptr);
}
```

This is m_resources:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<T*, unsigned int>> m_resources;
```

Comment: How do you populate `m_resources`?

Comment: Is `this` a valid pointer?

Comment: Visually, I cannot find any fault in the posted code. Use a memory debugger, the memory trashing may happen elsewhere. On [windows - visual leak debugger](https://vld.codeplex.com/) or on [Linux/Mac - valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Thanks. I'm using VS2015 on Win10. I followed the instructions to install, link and include VLD but it doesn't give me any extra output. Apparently there's an issue with console applications? Guess I have to use something else.